# How do I get a feeds or post specifically from a facebook group not from a facebook page having same name?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-group

I would like to get the feeds that were posted by members of facebook group (group is closed )through api. I want to use that result in my android app. There is a same id for page and group so I am not able to get the feeds from group (so I understand, there might be different issue).

Comment: There's no way a page and a group share the same ID. And if so, then you should report a facebook platform bug.

Comment: Thank you @ifaour  . Actually I had taken the wrong path.